Degree of minimal polynomial in field theory
I'm reading abstract algebra book and I've came across such lemma:
Let $\alpha, \beta$ be conjugate elements over field F and $\beta \in F(\alpha)$. Prove that in this case there exists unique automorphism $F(\alpha) \to F(\alpha)$ that preserves field $F$ and maps $\alpha \to \beta$
the only thing that comes to my mind with automorphism and cojugation is the fact that every algebraic element comes to it's conjugate under automorphism... but I think it's useless here.

Hint: Recall that if $m_{\alpha}$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ then there is very natural isomorphism $F[x]/(m_{\alpha})\cong F(\alpha)$ given by $f+(m_{\alpha})\to f(\alpha)$ for $f\in F[x]$. So if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial, we have a chain of isomorphisms:
$F(\alpha)\cong F[x]/(m_{\alpha})\cong F(\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha)$
Use it to construct the required automorphism. Uniqueness is easy to prove.

Mark, please do not answer very low-quality questions anymore.

@Angelo And why is it "very low quality"? OP at least wrote a a few words about his thoughts. If he never saw similar ideas before, the chances to come up with a proof are very low. I wonder what book left this statement as an exercise.

Mark, if the post was closed, there has to be a good reason. Of course, without doubts, it was not a passable question.

@Mark, here are my thoughts, help me get through it =)
$F(\alpha)$ is a set of rational functions $\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}, f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$. Let's $\phi: \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \to \frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}$.


$\phi(\alpha) = \beta$, because $\alpha, \beta$ are zero polynomials: $\phi(\frac{\alpha}{1}) = \frac{\beta}{1}$


$\phi$ is a homomorphism


$\phi$ preserves $F$


Is $\phi$ bijective? yes, kernel is trivial and it's surjective by definition.


since $\beta \in F(\alpha) \to F(\alpha) = F(\beta)$, but where should we use that alpha and beta are conjugate?



@Mark, and thanks for your answer!
